# Inject using @EJB or to do Lookup eachtime in Servlet Filter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, orm, ejb-3.0

I want to inject the EJB (Local) into the Servlet Filter and the EAR is deployed on Weblogic 11g.

My question is:

Shall the @EJB Annotation will work on Weblogic 11g or it will be ignored?
OR
I have to do look up as below and mention the references in web.xml and weblogic xml file:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory" );
Context ctx = new InitialContext( env );
ctx.lookup( "myejb" );
```

Thanks

Comment: I am asking this question because when I do @EJB it is throwing NPE where If I do look up then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to just supprot as below

More Rerference: [JSF Application that uses managed-bean and ejb](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/jsf-managedBean-and-ejb/)

Remote and Local Interface

```
    @Remote
    public interface IPersonEAORemote {
        public void show();
    }

    @Local
    public interface IPersonEAOLocal {
        public void show();
    }
```

EJB Bean

```
    @Stateless(name = "PersonEAO", mappedName = "PersonEAO")
    public class PersonEAOBean implements IPersonEAORemote, IPersonEAOLocal {
        /* if you use JPA
        @PersistenceContext(name = "EJB_DEMO")
        private EntityManager em;
        */

        public void show() {
            System.out.println("Good Luck!");
        }
    }
```

Simple Client

```
    public class Client {
        private IPersonEAORemote personEAO;

        private void init() {
            try {
                final Context context = getInitialContext();
                personEAO = (IPersonEAORemote)context.lookup("PersonEAO#<your package name>.IPersonEAORemote");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            // WebLogic Server 10.x connection details
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://127.0.0.1:7101");
            return new InitialContext(env);
        }


        public void show() {
            personEAO.show());
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.init();
            client.show();
        }
    }
```

ManageBean : Let's say, if you use JSF, your backing bean is here;

```
    public class JSFBackingBean {
        @EJB
        IPersonEAORemote personEAO;

        public void show() {
            personEAO.show();
        }
    }
```

For JBoss 5 :

```
    Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY ---> org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
    Context.PROVIDER_URL ---->http://localhost:1099
```

Comment: I am sorry, I provided very less info here. Consumer uses the EJB local interfaces to be injected in Servlet Filter and the EAR is deployed on Weblogic 11g. Shall @EJB annotation to be injected in Servlet Filter work on Weblogic 11g or to do look up as mentioned above in my post?